# The order of the smallest possible non trivial group containing elements $x$ and $y$

Tags: abstract-algebra

I've not sure about the way I tried the problem

> The order of the smallest possible non trivial group containing elements $x$ and $y$ such that $x^7=y^2=1$ and $yx=x^4y$ is (A) $1$ (B) $2$ (C) $7$ (D) $14$

Here's my try:

For any group of order $2, say~\{e,a\}$ taking $x=e,y=a$ satisfies both the equation. Can I conclude then the required order is $2$?

Comment: Yes, your group is correct. The group is clearly non-trivial since it has a non-identity element, and $yx = ye = y = e y = e^4 y = x^4y$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you wanted the desire group *smallest*, so this means to me that it should be of smallest order, and of course non-trivial; therefore your selection is completely right. The following codes confirms that:

```
 gap> f:=FreeGroup("a","b");;
      a:=f.1;;   b:=f.2;;   
      t:=f/[a^7,b^2,b*a*b^(-1)*a^(-4)];;
      StructureDescription(t);


    > "C2"
```

Note that $$yxy^{-1}=x^4\to y^2xy^{-2}=x^{4^2}=x^{16}\to  x^{15}=1$$
but $x^7=1$, so $x=1$.

Comment: GAP is our friend! +1

Comment: @amWhy: Congratulations Amy. America beat Mexico 2-0 last night to qualify for the World Cup in Brazil. ;-)